# convert sequence to a map using yq and use it as input to terraform

Tags: yq

I'm try to covert a sequence into a map.

convert from

```
-cidr: 192.168.0.1/32
 description: "test"
-cidr: 192.168.0.2/32
 description: "test"
```

to

```
Rule1:
-cidr: 192.168.0.1/32
 description: "test"
Rule2:
-cidr: 192.168.0.2/32
 description: "test"
```

Which will be again used in terraform under `locals.tf` file

Comment: Neither input nor output is valid YAML. Also, please specify, [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) (and which version) of `yq` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your input and output are not valid YAML. They would be with spaces after the dashes. Assuming this correction, you'd need to turn the array into an object, using the array indices as keys, and wrapping the items into one-elemented arrays.

You also didn't specify, [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) (and which version) of `yq` you are using. Here's an approach using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/) version 3.2.2:

```bash
yq -y 'with_entries(.key |= "Rule\(.+1)" | .value |= [.])'
```

```yaml
Rule1:
  - cidr: 192.168.0.1/32
    description: test
Rule2:
  - cidr: 192.168.0.2/32
    description: test
```

Here's another one using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.34.2:

```bash
yq 'with_entries(.key |= "Rule" + (. + 1 | . type = "!!str") | .value |= [.])'
```

```yaml
Rule1:
  - cidr: 192.168.0.1/32
    description: "test"
Rule2:
  - cidr: 192.168.0.2/32
    description: "test"
```